# Recursive depth function on an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, higher-order-functions

I have an array of objects like this input, and I want to nest some objects inside another objects (based if their parentId is the parents' forumId),

I got the function working but up to 1 depth, how can I get it working for n depth? Any idea or optimizations are appreciated!

**EDIT: After pointing out, the input isn't necessarily ordered.**

```js
const input = [
  {
    forumId: 1,
    parentId: null,
    forumName: "Main",
    forumDescription: "",
    forumLocked: false,
    forumDisplay: true,
  },
  {
    forumId: 2,
    parentId: 1,
    forumName: "Announcements",
    forumDescription: "Announcements & Projects posted here",
    forumLocked: false,
    forumDisplay: true,
  },
  {
    forumId: 3,
    parentId: 1,
    forumName: "General",
    forumDescription: "General forum, talk whatever you want here",
    forumLocked: false,
    forumDisplay: true,
  },
  {
    forumId: 4,
    parentId: 3,
    forumName: "Introduction",
    forumDescription: "A warming introduction for newcomers here",
    forumLocked: false,
    forumDisplay: true,
  },
];

function processInput(forumInput) {
  const topLevelForums = forumInput.filter(function (forum) {
    return forum.parentId === null;
  });

  let output = topLevelForums;

  forumInput.forEach(function (forum) {
    if (forum.parentId !== null) {
      const forumParentId = forum.parentId;
      output.forEach(function (parentForum, idx) {
        if (parentForum.forumId === forumParentId) {
          if (!output[idx].hasOwnProperty("subForums")) {
            output[idx].subForums = [];
          }
          parentForum.subForums.push(forum);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  return output;
}
```

This is the **expected output**:

```
[
  {
    forumId: 1,
    parentId: null,
    forumName: "Main",
    forumDescription: "",
    forumLocked: false,
    forumDisplay: true,
    subForums: [
      {
        forumId: 2,
        parentId: 1,
        forumName: "Announcements",
        forumDescription: "Announcements & Projects posted here",
        forumLocked: false,
        forumDisplay: true,
      },
      {
        forumId: 3,
        parentId: 1,
        forumName: "General",
        forumDescription: "General forum, talk whatever you want here",
        forumLocked: false,
        forumDisplay: true,
        subForums: [
          {
            forumId: 4,
            parentId: 3,
            forumName: "Introduction",
            forumDescription: "A warming introduction for newcomers here",
            forumLocked: false,
            forumDisplay: true,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

This is the **current output**:

```
[
  {
    forumDescription: "",
    forumDisplay: true,
    forumId: 1,
    forumLocked: false,
    forumName: "Main",
    parentId: null,
    subForums: [
      {
        forumDescription: "Announcements & Projects posted here",
        forumDisplay: true,
        forumId: 2,
        forumLocked: false,
        forumName: "Announcements",
        parentId: 1,
      },
      {
        forumDescription: "General forum, talk whatever you want here",
        forumDisplay: true,
        forumId: 3,
        forumLocked: false,
        forumName: "General",
        parentId: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Comment: In `input`, the parent forum id always **before** its children. Will that always be true? Or can it be that a parent appears *after* its children in that array?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder not ordered, they can appear randomly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A wonderful opportunity to learn about mutual recursion. The input can be in **any** order -

```js
function makeIndex (items, indexer)
{ const append = (r, k, v) =>
    r.set(k, (r.get(k) || []).concat([ v ]))

  return items.reduce
    ( (r, i) => append(r, indexer(i), i)
    , new Map
    )
}

function makeTree (index, root = null)
{ const many = (all = []) =>
    all.map(one)

  const one = (forum = {}) =>
    ( { ...forum
      , subforums: many(index.get(forum.forumId))
      }
    )

  return many(index.get(root))
}

const input =
  [{forumId:1,parentId:null,forumName:"Main",forumDescription:"",forumLocked:false,forumDisplay:true},{forumId:2,parentId:1,forumName:"Announcements",forumDescription:"Announcements & Projects posted here",forumLocked:false,forumDisplay:true},{forumId:3,parentId:1,forumName:"General",forumDescription:"General forum, talk whatever you want here",forumLocked:false,forumDisplay:true},{forumId:4,parentId:3,forumName:"Introduction",forumDescription:"A warming introduction for newcomers here",forumLocked:false,forumDisplay:true}]

const result =
  makeTree(makeIndex(input, forum => forum.parentId))

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

```
[
  {
    "forumId": 1,
    "parentId": null,
    "forumName": "Main",
    "forumDescription": "",
    "forumLocked": false,
    "forumDisplay": true,
    "subforums": [
      {
        "forumId": 2,
        "parentId": 1,
        "forumName": "Announcements",
        "forumDescription": "Announcements & Projects posted here",
        "forumLocked": false,
        "forumDisplay": true,
        "subforums": []
      },
      {
        "forumId": 3,
        "parentId": 1,
        "forumName": "General",
        "forumDescription": "General forum, talk whatever you want here",
        "forumLocked": false,
        "forumDisplay": true,
        "subforums": [
          {
            "forumId": 4,
            "parentId": 3,
            "forumName": "Introduction",
            "forumDescription": "A warming introduction for newcomers here",
            "forumLocked": false,
            "forumDisplay": true,
            "subforums": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

**make it modular**

Above `makeIndex` is written in a way that it can index any array of datum, but `makeTree` makes assumptions like `...forum`, `subforums`, and `forum.forumId`. When we think about our code in modules, we are forced to draw lines of separation and consequently our programs become untangled.

Below, `input` is defined in `main` and so we keep all knowledge about `input` here -

```js
// main.js
import { tree } from './tree'

const input =
  [{forumId:1,parentId:null,forumName:"Main",forumDescription:"",forumLocked:false,forumDisplay:true},{forumId:2,parentId:1,forumName:"Announcements",forumDescription:"Announcements & Projects posted here",forumLocked:false,forumDisplay:true},{forumId:3,parentId:1,forumName:"General",forumDescription:"General forum, talk whatever you want here",forumLocked:false,forumDisplay:true},{forumId:4,parentId:3,forumName:"Introduction",forumDescription:"A warming introduction for newcomers here",forumLocked:false,forumDisplay:true}]

const result =
  tree
    ( input                    // <- array of nodes
    , forum => forum.parentId  // <- foreign key
    , (forum, subforums) =>    // <- node reconstructor function
        ({ ...forum, subforums: subforums(forum.forumId) }) // <- primary key
    )

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

When I make a `tree`, I don't want to have to think about making an `index` first. In our original program, how was I supposed to know a `tree` needed an `index`? Let's let the `tree` module worry about that -

```js
// tree.js
import { index } from './index'

const empty =
  {}

function tree (all, indexer, maker, root = null)
{ const cache =
    index(all, indexer)

  const many = (all = []) =>
    all.map(x => one(x))
                             // zero knowledge of forum object shape
  const one = (single) =>
    maker(single, next => many(cache.get(next)))

  return many(cache.get(root))
}

export { empty, tree } // <-- public interface
```

We could have written the `index` function directly in the `tree` module but the behavior we want is not specific to trees. Writing a separate `index` module makes more sense -

```js
// index.js
const empty = _ =>
  new Map

const update = (r, k, t) =>
  r.set(k, t(r.get(k)))

const append = (r, k, v) =>
  update(r, k, (all = []) => [...all, v])

const index = (all = [], indexer) =>
  all.reduce
      ( (r, v) => append(r, indexer(v), v) // zero knowledge of v shape
      , empty()
      )

export { empty, index, append } // <-- public interface
```

Writing modules helps you think about your code in meaningful parts and promotes a high degree of code reusability.

Comment: I knew from the first sentence who had written this one!  Nice work, as always!

Comment: `"A wonderful opportunity to learn about mutual recursion"` @ScottSauyet The famous quote :D

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since this has been asked, but since the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62138087/6567275) has been [linked in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70051788/6567275) and I find it too complex, I'll add my answer here as well:

- Keeping it abstract enough to deal with arbitrary trees? OK, fine.
- Random order of parents/children in the input? Sure, why not.
- And on top of that, in a single sweep over the input array

```
function makeTree(input, indexer, maker, root = null) {
  const cache = new Map;
  // get or create (and return) children array for the passed key;
  const getChildrenArray = key => cache.get(key) || cache.set(key, []).get(key);

  for (let item of input) {
    getChildrenArray(indexer(item)).push(
      maker(item, getChildrenArray)
    );
  }
  
  return cache.get(root);
}
```

```js
const input = [
  {
    forumId: 1,
    parentId: null,
    forumName: "Main",
    forumDescription: "",
    forumLocked: false,
    forumDisplay: true,
  },
  {
    forumId: 2,
    parentId: 1,
    forumName: "Announcements",
    forumDescription: "Announcements & Projects posted here",
    forumLocked: false,
    forumDisplay: true,
  },
  {
    forumId: 3,
    parentId: 1,
    forumName: "General",
    forumDescription: "General forum, talk whatever you want here",
    forumLocked: false,
    forumDisplay: true,
  },
  {
    forumId: 4,
    parentId: 3,
    forumName: "Introduction",
    forumDescription: "A warming introduction for newcomers here",
    forumLocked: false,
    forumDisplay: true,
  },
];

function makeTree(input, indexer, maker, root = null) {
  const cache = new Map;
  // get or create (and return) children array for the passed key;
  const getChildrenArray = key => cache.get(key) || cache.set(key, []).get(key);

  for (let item of input) {
    getChildrenArray(indexer(item)).push(
      maker(item, getChildrenArray)
    );
  }
  
  return cache.get(root);
}

const result = makeTree(
  input,
  item => item.parentId,
  (item, getChildrenFor) => ({ 
    ...item, 
    subForums: getChildrenFor(item.forumId) 
  }),
  null
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object which takes all relation from an object with child to parent and parent to childand get the nodes which have no parent.

This approach works for any depth, unsorted data and uses only a single loop.

```js
const
    input = [{ forumId: 3, parentId: 1, forumName: "General", forumDescription: "General forum, talk whatever you want here", forumLocked: false, forumDisplay: true }, { forumId: 2, parentId: 1, forumName: "Announcements", forumDescription: "Announcements & Projects posted here", forumLocked: false, forumDisplay: true }, { forumId: 4, parentId: 3, forumName: "Introduction", forumDescription: "A warming introduction for newcomers here", forumLocked: false, forumDisplay: true }, { forumId: 1, parentId: null, forumName: "Main", forumDescription: "", forumLocked: false, forumDisplay: true }],
    tree = function(data, root) {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(o => {
            Object.assign(t[o.forumId] = t[o.forumId] || {}, o);
            t[o.parentId] = t[o.parentId] || {};
            t[o.parentId].subForums = t[o.parentId].subForums || [];
            t[o.parentId].subForums.push(t[o.forumId]);
        });
        return t[root].subForums;
    }(input, null);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, this approach works with unsorted data as long as the items has a defined parent.

Comment: My experiment to check that it worked with unsorted data was flawed, sorry. The issue of not raising an issue when the parent doesn't exist is real, though.

Comment: @NinaScholz I get weird output keys on the objects like "stateNames", "session", "$setCalled", "emitter", "_events", I'm using Node if that changes something.

Answer (score 1):

Since parents might be after the children in the input, I think I'd approach it by building a `Map` of forums by ID, then adding the children to them:

```
function processInput(forumInput) {
    // Get a map of forums by ID
    const forumsById = new Map();
    for (const forum of forumInput) {
        forumsById.set(forum.forumId, forum);
    }

    // Add child forums to their parents
    for (const forum of forumInput) {
        const {parentId} = forum;
        if (parentId !== null) {
            const parent = forumsById.get(forum.parentId);
            parent.subForums = parent.subForums || []; // Or you could use `?? []` now
            parent.subForums.push(forum);
        }
    }

    // Return the parents array
    return [...forumsById.values()].filter(({parentId}) => parentId === null);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const input = [
  {
    forumId: 1,
    parentId: null,
    forumName: "Main",
    forumDescription: "",
    forumLocked: false,
    forumDisplay: true,
  },
  {
    forumId: 2,
    parentId: 1,
    forumName: "Announcements",
    forumDescription: "Announcements & Projects posted here",
    forumLocked: false,
    forumDisplay: true,
  },
  {
    forumId: 3,
    parentId: 1,
    forumName: "General",
    forumDescription: "General forum, talk whatever you want here",
    forumLocked: false,
    forumDisplay: true,
  },
  {
    forumId: 4,
    parentId: 3,
    forumName: "Introduction",
    forumDescription: "A warming introduction for newcomers here",
    forumLocked: false,
    forumDisplay: true,
  },
];

function processInput(forumInput) {
    // Get a map of forums by ID
    const forumsById = new Map();
    for (const forum of forumInput) {
        forumsById.set(forum.forumId, forum);
    }

    // Add child forums to their parents
    for (const forum of forumInput) {
        const {parentId} = forum;
        if (parentId !== null) {
            const parent = forumsById.get(forum.parentId);
            parent.subForums = parent.subForums || []; // Or you could use `?? []` now
            parent.subForums.push(forum);
        }
    }

    // Return the parents array
    return [...forumsById.values()].filter(({parentId}) => parentId === null);
}

console.log(processInput(input));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Note that the above will throw an error if a forum claims to be in a parent forum that isn't in the input.

Answer (score 1):

I think the systematic approach is
1. create a map of id to object
2. create a map of parent -> children
3. add all the parent to the results
4. recursively add children (subforums)

```
const input = [
  {
    forumId: 1,
    parentId: null,
    forumName: "Main",
    forumDescription: "",
    forumLocked: false,
    forumDisplay: true,
  },
  {
    forumId: 2,
    parentId: 1,
    forumName: "Announcements",
    forumDescription: "Announcements & Projects posted here",
    forumLocked: false,
    forumDisplay: true,
  },
  {
    forumId: 3,
    parentId: 1,
    forumName: "General",
    forumDescription: "General forum, talk whatever you want here",
    forumLocked: false,
    forumDisplay: true,
  },
  {
    forumId: 4,
    parentId: 3,
    forumName: "Introduction",
    forumDescription: "A warming introduction for newcomers here",
    forumLocked: false,
    forumDisplay: true,
  },
];

const mapIdToForums = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.forumId] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {});

const mapForumsToSubForums = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  parentId = cur.parentId || ""; // no parent
  acc[parentId] = acc[parentId] || [];
  acc[parentId].push(cur);
  return acc;
}, {});


const addChildren = (parent) => {
  var children = mapForumsToSubForums[parent.forumId];
  if (children) {
    parent.subForums = children

    children.forEach(c => addChildren(c));
  }
};

results = mapForumsToSubForums[""];
results.forEach(p => addChildren(p));
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

As some other answers, I would use a `Map` to key nodes by their `forumId`, and then populate the children inside the corresponding values:

```js
let input = [{ forumId: 3, parentId: 1, forumName: "General", forumDescription: "General forum, talk whatever you want here", forumLocked: false, forumDisplay: true }, { forumId: 2, parentId: 1, forumName: "Announcements", forumDescription: "Announcements & Projects posted here", forumLocked: false, forumDisplay: true }, { forumId: 4, parentId: 3, forumName: "Introduction", forumDescription: "A warming introduction for newcomers here", forumLocked: false, forumDisplay: true }, { forumId: 1, parentId: null, forumName: "Main", forumDescription: "", forumLocked: false, forumDisplay: true }];

let root = {};
let map = new Map(input.map(o => [o.forumId, ({...o})]))
map.forEach(o => (p => p.subForms = (p.subForms || []).concat(o))(map.get(o.parentId) || root));
let result = root.subForms;

console.log(result);
```