# JS Recursion Algo problem with positioning elements into correct order

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, recursion

I have a problem that I have been racking my head on and seem to be stuck. I have an array of entities that I need to sort but also nest within one another if the condition is met. They also need to be sorted by count within their own scope.

```
let entity = {
  company: {id: string, parent_id?: string, count: number}
}

let arr = entity[]
```

What I need to do is loop through the array and see which entities are children of other entities and nest them accordingly. So as an example

```
let arr = [{company: {id: 1, count: 10}}, {company: {id: 2, parent_id: 1, count: 3}}, {company:{id: 3: parent_id: 1, count: 5}}, {company: {id: 4, parent_id: 2, count: 4}}, {company: {id: 5, count: 1}]

After computation this should be:

[
  {company: {
    id: 1, 
    count: 10, 
    children: [
      {company: {
        id: 3,
        parent_id: 1,
        count: 5
      }},
      {company: {
        id: 2,
        parent_id: 1
        count: 3,
        children: [
          {company: {
            id: 4,
            parent_id: 2,
            count: 4
          }
        ]
      }}
    ]
  }},
  {company: {
    id: 5, count: 1
  }}
]
```

I essentially need to "unflatten" the map, I have tried some recursive strategies like saving to a set the initial entities and then looping through the initial array and trying to nest/remove entities as needed, but havent found success so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concept, with lodash as the only dependency (both `_.keyBy` and `_.sortBy` can easily be written in pure javascript).

It breaks down the problem in two steps: first nesting, second recursively sorting entities.

It edits the original arguments, you can do `_.cloneDeep` to keep the input unchanged.

```
import _ from "lodash";

type Company = {id: string, parent_id?: string, count: number};
type Entity = {company: Company};
type NestedEntity = {company: Company & {children?: NestedEntity[]}};

// entities is the input

const entities_by_id = _.keyBy(entities, 'company.id');

// This is the output
let results: NestedEntity [] = [];

// Step 1: nest entities
for (const entity of entities) {
  if (entity.company.parent_id) {
    const parent = entities[company.parent_id];
    parent.company.children = parent.company.children ?? [];
    parent.company.children.push(entity);
  } else {
    results.push(entity);
  }
}

//Step 2: sort recursively
function sortEntities(entityArray) {
  const sorted = _.sortBy(entityArray, "company.count").reverse();

  for (const entity of sorted) {
    if (entity.company.children) {
      entity.company.children = sortEntities(entity.company.children);
    }
  }

  return sorted;
}

results = sortEntities(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a single loop approach without using libraries.

This approach takes this node and the parent node (this virtually only with children) and builds a nested tree.

At the end, the root node companie's children are returned.

```js
const
    getTree = (data, root) => {
        const
            getLeaf = (object, keys, last = {}) =>
                keys.reduce((o, k, i, { length }) =>
                    o[k] = o[k] || (i + 1 === length ? last : {}), object),
            t = {};

        data.forEach(({ company }) => {
            Object.assign(getLeaf(t, [company.id, 'company']), company);
            getLeaf(t, [company.parent_id, 'company', 'children'], [])
                .push(t[company.id]);
        });

        return t[root].company.children;
    },
    data = [{ company: { id: 1, count: 10 } }, { company: { id: 2, parent_id: 1, count: 3 } }, { company: { id: 3, parent_id: 1, count: 5 } }, { company: { id: 4, parent_id: 2, count: 4 } }, { company: { id: 5, count: 1 } }],
    tree = getTree(data);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: So I am going with this as its working, but I am confused about the root? Maybe I am not understanding something, but I don't see where we pass the value to it and it doesn't have a default value

Comment: it takes the value of missing properties. `undefined` is the key for all root elements.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for using this with TS as it doesnt allow for undefined to be a key value

`Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.`

Comment: basically it is either a number, of `id` or `parent_id` or `'undefined'` as string.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63855623) that tries to solve such problems generically.  (Most of this is in the *Update* in that answer.)  While this is a slight tweak from that, as I'm still fiddling, it should solve the problem reasonably well:

```js
// generic solution
const forest = (build, isChild, root) => (xs) => 
  xs .filter (x => isChild (root, x))
     .map (node => build (node, root => forest (build, isChild, root) (xs)))
    
// comparator for sorting
const byCountDesc = ({company: {count: a = 0}}, {company: {count: b = 0}}) => b - a

// customization for input structure.
const transform = (xs) => forest (
  (x, f) => ({company: {...x.company, children: f(x .company .id) .sort (byCountDesc)}}),
  (id, {company: {parent_id}}) => parent_id == id,
  null
) (xs) .sort (byCountDesc)


// sample data
const arr = [{company: {id: 1, count: 10}}, {company: {id: 2, parent_id: 1, count: 3}}, {company: {id: 3, parent_id: 1, count: 5}}, {company: {id: 4, parent_id: 2, count: 4}}, {company: {id: 5, count: 1}}]

// demo
console .log (transform (arr))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The first parameter to `forest` is a function that accepts an element and a function that will be called on a reference to the element (for us it's the element's `id`, but see that answer for other possibilities) to return a substructure.  Our function will build out the current node, by making a near-clone of the original with a `children` property pointing to the result of calling the function, passing the `id`.

The second parameter tells us if one node is the child of another.  Here's its just matching the `id` with a `parent_id`.

The third parameter is the root value, `null` in our case because elements with no parent have no `parent_id`.  Other circumstances might have `0` or some other dedicated id.  And there are other possibilities as discussed there.

`forest` then returns a function which takes your flat array and restructures it as desirred.

If you mind having empty `children` nodes here and there, then we could replace the customized function with

```js
const transform = forest (
  (x, f, kids = f(x.company.id)) => ({
    company: {...x.company, ...(kids.length ? {children: kids} : {})}
  }),
  (id, {company: {parent_id}}) => parent_id == id,
  null
)
```

For another generic approach, using similar arguments, but a different design, see the [answer from Thankyou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63856655) in that same question.

Comment: Added an update because I'd forgotten to handle the sorting.

Comment: that `sort` is a little tricky, eh? at first I was confused why my root level nodes weren't sorted...

Comment: @Thankyou: not hard to implement, but certainly annoying!  I considered an alternative of an after-the-fact recursive sort.  I probably would have done that if this version were any more tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map to key your objects by their id, and then iterate them to add them to the children list of their parent. A temporary root object helps to collect the result array:

```js
let arr = [{company: {id: 1, count: 10}}, {company: {id: 2, parent_id: 1, count: 3}}, {company: {id: 3, parent_id: 1, count: 5}}, {company: {id: 4, parent_id: 2, count: 4}}, {company: {id: 5, count: 1}}];

let result = [], root = { children: result };
let map = new Map(arr.map(({company}) => [company.id, {company:{...company}}]));
for (let o of map.values()) {
    ((map.get(o.company.parent_id)?.company || root).children ||= []).push(o);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A great opportunity to learn about reusable modules and mutual recursion. This solution in this answer solves your specific problem without any modification of the modules written in other answers.

---

First, to solve the sorting portion of the problem we will compare by `count` using the Comparison module, presented in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61049318/633183). If this feels strange to you, check out the post to see a wide variety of ways in which the module is useful -

```js
import * as Comparison from "./Comparison"

const byCount =
  Comparison.map                            // map a comparison
    ( Comparison.desc                       // default "descending" comparison
    , ({ company: { count = 0 }}) => count  // path to count property
    )

// ...
```

Second, to build the required `tree` using the Tree module, presented in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62970981/633183) -

```js
// ...

import { tree } from "./Tree"

const foreignKey = ({ company: { parent_id }}) =>
  parent_id

const input =
  [{company: {id: 1, count: 10}}, {company: {id: 2, parent_id: 1, count: 3}}, {company: {id: 3, parent_id: 1, count: 5}}, {company: {id: 4, parent_id: 2, count: 4}}, {company: {id: 5, count: 1}}]

const result =
  tree
    ( input
    , foreignKey        // <- your foreign key
    , (node, get) =>
        ( { ...node
          , children:
              get(node.company.id) // <- your primary key
                .sort(byCount)  // <- sort children
          }
        )
    )
    .sort(byCount) // <- sort root elements

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

Output; sibling nodes are sorted by `count` in descending order -

```js
[
  {
    "company": {
      "id": 1,
      "count": 10
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "company": {
          "id": 3,
          "parent_id": 1,
          "count": 5
        },
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "company": {
          "id": 2,
          "parent_id": 1,
          "count": 3
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "company": {
              "id": 4,
              "parent_id": 2,
              "count": 4
            },
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "company": {
      "id": 5,
      "count": 1
    },
    "children": []
  }
]
```

---

**branching implementations**

@ScottSauyet makes me consider alternate designs for `tree`, especially considering renaming it to `forest`. One particular improvement I had in mind was to make `tree` simply take a pair of primary and foreign keys along with a child transform function -

```js
// Main.js

const input =
  // ...

const byCount =
  // ...

const fk = ({ company: { parent_id }}) =>
  parent_id

const pk = ({ company: { id }}) =>
  id

const result =
  tree
    ( input
    , [ pk, fk ] // <- primary/foreign key pair
    , children => ({ children: children.sort(byCount) }) // <- transform
    )
    .sort(byCount)

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

The result is valid of course, so long as we update `tree` to make it so! -

```js
// Tree.js (revised)

function tree (all, [pk, fk], maker, root)   // <-
{ const cache =
    index(all, fk)

  const many = (all = []) =>
    all.map(x => one(x))
    
  const one = (single) =>
    ({ ...single, ...maker(many(cache.get(pk(single)))) }) // <-

  return many(cache.get(root))
}
```

One downside to this is `single` and (return value of) `maker` are assumed to be objects, `{...}`, and so it restricts some of the tree shapes you can build. A more sophisticated merge could use runtime type-checking but I'm wary to go down that path. Another downside is all properties of `node` are included in the result whereas before we could pick all/any/none.