# How to Build a Dynamic object on JS From two arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I'm trying to build an array of objects from another two arrays, can someone help me out.

```
const parent =[
  { Id: 1, Cate: 'Accommodation', p_id: null },
  { Id: 4, Cate: 'National Travel', p_id: null }
]

const child =[
  { Id: 2, Cate: 'Hotel Accommodation', p_id: 1 },
  { Id: 3, Cate: 'Own arrangement', p_id: 1 },
  { Id: 5, Cate: 'Air', p_id: 4 },
  { Id: 6, Cate: 'Bus', p_id: 4 },
  { Id: 7, Cate: 'AC Volvo', p_id: 6 },
  { Id: 8, Cate: 'Luxury Bus', p_id: 6 },
  { Id: 9, Cate: 'Bus', p_id: 6 }
]

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    tittle: 'Accommodation',
    subItem: [
      { id: 2, tittle: 'Hotel Accommodation', subItems: [] },
      { id: 3, tittle: 'Own arrangement', subItems: [] },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    tittle: 'National Travel',
    subItem: [
      { id: 5, tittle: 'Air', subItems: [] },
      {
        id: 6,
        tittle: 'Bus',
        subItem: [
          { id: 7, tittle: 'AC Volvo' },
          { id: 5, tittle: 'Air' },
          { id: 8, tittle: 'Luxury Bus' },
          { id: 9, tittle: 'Bus' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

`parent` and `child` are the data I get from DB, now I need to change that into something looking like `data`. The thing is it has to be dynamic, as `subItems` can go long as it needs to be, how can I make something like that?

Comment: You can think about `recursive`.

Comment: @Phong Can you please show me an example.? I'm not so good at these.

Comment: `{ id: 5, tittle: 'Air' },` in  `id: 6 's subItem` is redundant, right?

Comment: Also, Does `subItems: []` in each parent act as a problem? Can we remove it in the result?

Comment: And what happens if the order of an item with `Id: 7` before `Id: 6`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can maintain two objects, a parent object, and a seen object. The seen object is responsible for storing all object ids already seen. That means, for each object in your array, you add it to the seen object.

```
// Seen object
{
  id_1: {id: id_1, ...}, /* id: 1 */
  id_2: {id: id_2, ...}, /* id: 2 */
  id_3: {id: id_3, ...}, /* id: 3 */
  id_4: {id: id_3, ...}  /* id: 4 */
}
```

As your parent objects come before they are used by your child objects, you can say that, when the `p_id` does not appear in the `seen` object, then the current object is a parent, and so, you can add its `id` to the `parents` object (in the above example, assume `id_1` is a parent). Keep in mind that this object also gets added to `seen`, and so, we can create a link between the parent object in `seen` and the one in `parents` by using its reference:

```
// Parents object
{
  id_1: /* ref: 1 */ <-- this refers to the seen[id_1] object
}
```

This link then allows us to change the object in `seen`, which would then result in the object in `parents` changing.

When an object is not a parent object, then it must be a child of another object we have already `seen`. In this example, assume that the object with `id_2` is a child/subItem of `id_1`. We can first find id_2's parent object (ie: the object with `id_1`) by looking it up in the `seen` object using `seen[p_id]`. Once we have the parent object for id_2, we can add a `subItem` array to it if needed, and add a reference to our id_2 object to this array:

```
// Seen object
{
  id_1: {id: id_1, ..., subItem: [/* ref: 2 */]}, /* id: 1 */
  id_2: {id: id_2, ...}, /* id: 2 */
}
```

we add id_2 as a reference by pushing in the object we added to `seen` by using `.push(seen[Id])`. We're adding a reference, as this will mean that if we change the object stored at id_2 in our seen object, then its changes will be reflected in id_1's subItem array.

Once we have iterated over all objects in our array, we can grab the values of our `parents` object, which contains references to the objects in `seen`, and those objects themselves also (may) contain references to other objects in `seen`. This gives us our final result:

```js
const parent =[ { Id: 1, Cate: 'Accommodation', p_id: null }, { Id: 4, Cate: 'National Travel', p_id: null } ];
const child = [ { Id: 2, Cate: 'Hotel Accommodation', p_id: 1 }, { Id: 3, Cate: 'Own arrangement', p_id: 1 }, { Id: 5, Cate: 'Air', p_id: 4 }, { Id: 6, Cate: 'Bus', p_id: 4 }, { Id: 7, Cate: 'AC Volvo', p_id: 6 }, { Id: 8, Cate: 'Luxury Bus', p_id: 6 }, { Id: 9, Cate: 'Bus', p_id: 6 } ];

const buildChildren = arr => {
  const parents = {}, seen = {};
  for(const {Id, Cate, p_id} of arr) {
    seen[Id] = {id: Id, title: Cate};
    if(p_id in seen) {
      const myParent = seen[p_id];
      myParent.subItem = myParent.subItem || []; // add subItem property if it doesn't exist yet
      myParent.subItem.push(seen[Id]); 
    } else { // Adding a new parent
      parents[Id] = seen[Id];
    }
    
  }
  return Object.values(parents);
}

console.log(buildChildren([...parent, ...child]));
```

Comment: I've figured out 3 issues. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66718770/how-to-build-a-dynamic-object-on-js-from-two-arrays/66728564#comment117956384_66718770), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66718770/how-to-build-a-dynamic-object-on-js-from-two-arrays/66728564#comment117956414_66718770), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66718770/how-to-build-a-dynamic-object-on-js-from-two-arrays/66728564#comment117956497_66718770)

Comment: Besides, [I've already given an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66718770/how-to-build-a-dynamic-object-on-js-from-two-arrays/66728564#66728564), you can give me your feedback, Thanks. +1 respect

Comment: Thanks, yes, I agree, that those are some issues that are worth looking into. To me it looks as though the `subItem` array is only required if it has values (I think OP made a mistake in their expected result). I also based my answer off of the original data, where parent objects come first, so I didn't bother to sort by the parent ids, but for a more generalized solution this would be a good thing to do. Your solution looks good, you could make it even more concise if you did something like     `(parentItemInStore.subItem ??= []).push(store[Id]);`, but that probably isn't as readable

Answer (score 3):

***The more concise and another detailed explanation (Based on [@Nick
Parsons's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66719016/9071943))***

Besides, *the problem is that `item.Id` make sure that it should be sorted ascending*.

---

The main ideas are:

1. Push the `"parent item"` into `result`.

   ```
   //If the first meet item with `parent ID` doesn't exist in store yet, then it should be the parent item
   if(!parentItemInStore) 
      result.push(store[Id]); // Adding a new parent
   ```
2. Add `subItem` into the `"parent item"`. By using the [`Reference Javascript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference), we can modify the item as well as reflect the reference item.

   ```
   else { // add subItem
      parentItemInStore.subItem ??= []; // Using `logical nullish assignment` to initialize subItem
      parentItemInStore.subItem.push(store[Id]); 
    }
   ```

```js
const parent =[ { Id: 1, Cate: 'Accommodation', p_id: null }, { Id: 4, Cate: 'National Travel', p_id: null } ];
const child = [ { Id: 2, Cate: 'Hotel Accommodation', p_id: 1 }, { Id: 3, Cate: 'Own arrangement', p_id: 1 }, { Id: 5, Cate: 'Air', p_id: 4 }, { Id: 7, Cate: 'AC Volvo', p_id: 6 }, { Id: 6, Cate: 'Bus', p_id: 4 }, { Id: 8, Cate: 'Luxury Bus', p_id: 6 }, { Id: 9, Cate: 'Bus', p_id: 6 } ];

const buildHierarchyCollection = flatItems => {
  flatItems.sort((a, b) => a.Id - b.Id); // this line is extremely important
  const result = [], store = {};
  for(const {Id, Cate, p_id} of flatItems) { 
    store[Id] = {Id, Cate}; // Store each item to keep the reference
    const parentItemInStore = store[p_id];
    if(!parentItemInStore) // If the first meet item with `parent ID` doesn't exist in store yet, then it should be the parent item
      result.push(store[Id]); // Adding a new parent
    else { // add subItem
      parentItemInStore.subItem ??= []; // Using `logical nullish assignment` to initialize subItem
      parentItemInStore.subItem.push(store[Id]); 
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(buildHierarchyCollection([...parent, ...child]));
```

**Solution 2: No need to sort**

```js
const parent =[ { Id: 1, Cate: 'Accommodation', p_id: null }, { Id: 4, Cate: 'National Travel', p_id: null } ];
const child = [ { Id: 2, Cate: 'Hotel Accommodation', p_id: 1 }, { Id: 3, Cate: 'Own arrangement', p_id: 1 }, { Id: 5, Cate: 'Air', p_id: 4 }, { Id: 7, Cate: 'AC Volvo', p_id: 6 }, { Id: 6, Cate: 'Bus', p_id: 4 }, { Id: 8, Cate: 'Luxury Bus', p_id: 6 }, { Id: 9, Cate: 'Bus', p_id: 6 } ];

const resolveParrentMissing = (store, currentItem) => {
  for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(store))
    if(value.p_id == currentItem.Id) {
      currentItem.subItem ??= [];
      currentItem.subItem.push(value); 
    }
}

const buildHierarchyCollection = flatItems => {
  const result = [], store = {};
  for(const {Id, Cate, p_id} of flatItems) {
    store[Id] = {Id, Cate, p_id}; // Store each item to keep the reference
    const parentItemInStore = store[p_id];
    if(!p_id) // If the first meet item with `parent ID` doesn't exist in store yet, then it should be the parent item
      result.push(store[Id]); // Adding a new parent
    else if(parentItemInStore) { // add subItem
      parentItemInStore.subItem ??= []; // Using `logical nullish assignment` to initialize subItem
      parentItemInStore.subItem.push(store[Id]); 
    }
    
    resolveParrentMissing(store, store[Id]);
  }
  
  return result;
}

const result = buildHierarchyCollection([...parent, ...child]);
console.log(result.map(({p_id, ...rest}) => rest));
```

Comment: This is making the perhaps unwarranted assumption that parents have lower-numbered ids than their children.  If that can be guaranteed, then this should work fine.  But if not, a technique like mine might be cleaner.

Comment: Yes, I do think so. @Scott Sauyet . actually, I have an loop called `resolveParrentMissing` be responsible for pushing all children items into the last parent. As a result, I don't need sort the array but still make sure the correct result.

Comment: Without testing it, I believe this would be fine.  For an elegant implementation of this technique, see [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62138087/1243641) from @Thankyou.

Comment: Yes, Thanks @ScottSauyet

Comment: And, while I'm pretty certain that this will be more efficient than my technique, mine would likely do fine for many datasets, and I find it much more elegant.

Comment: I agree with you. But in the case of the deep structure, we have to `recursive` multiple times leading throw `StackOverflowException` @ScottSauyet?

Comment: If you mean that this won't build a tree more than 10,000 levels deep, then yes, that's correct.  But if you have a structure like that, this is probably the least of your worries!

Comment: Yup. I got you. Thanks @ScottSauyet

Answer (score 2):

I think this approach is simpler than many others presented here.

```js
const makeForest = (xs, id) => 
  xs .filter ((x) => x.p_id == id) 
     .map (({Id, Cate, p_id}, _, __, subItems = makeForest (xs, Id)) => ({
       id: Id, tittle: Cate, ... (subItems.length ? {subItems} : {})
     }))

const parent = [{Id: 1, Cate: 'Accommodation', p_id: null}, {Id: 4, Cate: 'National Travel', p_id: null}]
const child = [{Id: 2, Cate: 'Hotel Accommodation', p_id: 1}, {Id: 3, Cate: 'Own arrangement', p_id: 1}, {Id: 5, Cate: 'Air', p_id: 4}, {Id: 6, Cate: 'Bus', p_id: 4}, {Id: 7, Cate: 'AC Volvo', p_id: 6}, {Id: 8, Cate: 'Luxury Bus', p_id: 6}, {Id: 9, Cate: 'Bus', p_id: 6}]

console .log (
  makeForest ([...parent, ...child])
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We start by combining the two arrays outside our main call.  This sort of code is easier to work with on a single list.

We filter out those items whose `p_id`s match an input parameter (and if we don't pass one, then the ones with `null` values will also match.  Then for each one of those, we build a new object, with `subItems` being created with a recursive all, using the same list and the current id.

If there are other fields we want to copy over directly, we can just destructure out a `...rest` parameter and include it in our mapping:

```js
const makeForest = (xs, id) => 
  xs .filter ((x) => x.p_id == id) 
     .map (({Id, Cate, p_id, ...rest}, _, __, subItems = makeForest (xs, Id)) => ({
       id: Id, tittle: Cate, ... rest, ... (subItems.length ? {subItems} : {})
     }))
```

### Update

[Nguyễn Văn Phong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66718770/how-to-build-a-dynamic-object-on-js-from-two-arrays/66719016#comment118281442_66857754) pointed out this simplification:

```js
const makeForest = (xs, id) => 
  xs .filter ((x) => x.p_id == id) 
     .map (({Id, Cate, p_id, subItems = makeForest (xs, Id)}) => ({
       id: Id, tittle: Cate, ... (subItems.length ? {subItems} : {})
     }))
```

which would work equally well with the `...rest` case.  It's very nice not to need those placeholder variables for the `map` call.

Comment: See also a generalization of this in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63855623/1243641).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for `- Recursive`. btw, Could you pls tell me the order params (I'm quite confused about the 4th parameter named `subItems`). According to [map's specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map),we just have 3 params. +1 respect.

Comment: I mean you can simply this like `({Id, Cate, p_id, subItems = makeForest (xs, Id)}`

Comment: Also, what happens if we have a deep structure. As a result, It's stack overflow, right? What's your opinion in this case? Which is better between your answer and [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66728564/9071943)

Comment: @Nguyễn: That's an interesting simplification.  When I start with almost any array method and want to default some parameters, I just assume I need placeholders for the index and array parameters.  But this shows I don't need them when I'm already destructuring an object.

Comment: @Nguyễn: That technique involves adding a default parameter at call-time so that I don't have to declare a local variable.  It helps me keep to write functions with only expressions, no statements.  But your simplification of it is nicer in this case.

Comment: @Nguyễn: "Also, what happens if we have a deep structure?"  I'm not sure what you're suggesting.  All this code does is to convert a flat array to a nested one (not a tree, but a forest) based on the relationship between `id`s of one object and `p_id`s of another.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const parent =[ { Id: 1, Cate: 'Accommodation', p_id: null }, { Id: 4, Cate: 'National Travel', p_id: null } ];
const child = [ { Id: 2, Cate: 'Hotel Accommodation', p_id: 1 }, { Id: 3, Cate: 'Own arrangement', p_id: 1 }, { Id: 5, Cate: 'Air', p_id: 4 }, { Id: 6, Cate: 'Bus', p_id: 4 }, { Id: 7, Cate: 'AC Volvo', p_id: 6 }, { Id: 8, Cate: 'Luxury Bus', p_id: 6 }, { Id: 9, Cate: 'Bus', p_id: 6 } ];

function prepardata(parent, child) {
    // map to hold all the values of parent and child arrays
    const map = {};
    // map to hold final result
    let item = {};
    // add parent elements to map
    for (let i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
        map[parent[i].Id] = parent[i];
    }
    // add child elements to map
    for (let i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
        // adding empty subItems array to every child category
        child[i]["subItems"] = [];
        map[child[i].Id] = child[i];
    }
    /**
     * At this point we have map ready with key as Id and value as
     * the object.
     * Using for-in to iterate over the map where key is Id
     */
    for (let key in map) {
    // if map has a key with value of the current entry p_id (map[key].p_id))
    if (map.hasOwnProperty(map[key].p_id)) {
        let parentCat = map[map[key].p_id];     // parent category element is the entry in map with value equal to p_id
        let childCat = map[key];    // child category element is the entry in map with value equal to key
            // Elements with p_id as null should be at the top level
            if (!parentCat.p_id) {
                // If final item map does not have an entry, then add it
                if (!item[parentCat.Id]) {
                    item[parentCat.Id] = {
                        id: parentCat.Id,
                        title: parentCat.Cate,
                        subItems: [childCat]
                    }
                } else {
                    // else just push the element in the existing parent categories subitems
                    item[parentCat.Id]["subItems"].push(childCat);
                }
            } else {
                // Else it's a sub category, the item needs to be pushed under its subItems array
                if (item[parentCat.p_id]) {
                    item[parentCat.p_id]["subItems"].filter(s => s.Id === childCat.p_id)[0]["subItems"].push(childCat);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // finally return the values from item map.
    return Object.values(item);
}

const data = prepardata(parent, child);
console.log(data);
```

You can use javascript `map` and `filter` to achieve this result. Iterate over the parent array to get the `id` and `title` and filter the child array to get only items with matching `p_id`.

```
const data = [];
parent.map(p => {
    const item = {
        id: p.Id,
        title: p.Cate,
        subItem: child.filter(c => c.p_id === p.Id)
    }
    data.push(item);
});
```

**Edit**
I've added snippet with the updated solution which supports multiple levels as my initial answer only supported 2 levels. Accepted answer by @Nick Parsons is correct and also shorter version but I'm still updating this answer to complete it.

Comment: i tried it, but it doesn't get the 3rd level of subitems. like, there'll be sub-items to sub-items, it can go on, this way I can only get two levels of subitems.